# Events in Global.asax are not firing

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

In my ASP.Net application, I can't get the events in Global.asax to fire on my machine.  For instance, Session_Start will not fire.

The same Global.asax works fine on other development machines in my office.

I have tried:

- Both the ASP.Net Development Server
  and my local IIS
- Rebooting the machine
- Removing and recreating the file from
  the project (including deleting it
  from disk)
- All machines are configured the with 
  the same level of software (VS2008
  SP1, .Net 3.5, XP)

This is driving me crazy, any help out there?

EDIT: Since the application works on other machines, I don't think it is directly related to the contents of Global.asax.  For some reason, my machine does not process the files.  I have done a repair of VS 2008 and .Net 2.0.  Any other ideas?

EDIT: The application running on all three machines is being pulled directly from source control.  It is definitely something specific to the one machine.

Thanks,

Pat

Comment: is it the same asp.net project on all machines?

Answer (score 7):

Application level events only need proper naming to work. Is your codebehind class being designated in your Global.asax file?

```
<%@ Application Inherits="YourNamespace.YourApplicationClass" Language="C#" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot but I have been bitten by this before.  When you created your Global.asax.cs file did you make sure to include a basic Global.asax file in your project?

Also make sure that the **inherits** property in that Global.asax is pointing to your custom class (namespace and all) in your Global.asax.cs file.

I had this problem once and it was because I totally forgot to make the Global.asax file and hook it up to my class.  I had just copied the Global.asax.cs from another project that did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

becuase project is compiled first and then you have add or modify or changed location of global.asax.vb.

Solution :- Just remove debug folder. Clean project and then rebuild whole project.

Regards,
Mihir

Answer (score 0):

As I write [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942797/global-asax-not-firing-for-aspx-pages-in-iis7/42981784#42981784), in my case, I was publish my site in production and I miss copy to server **App_global.asax.compiled** file. For this reason was not fire the Events inside Global.asax.

Hope anyelse help this tips, I lost 8 hours seeking.

Answer (score -1):

If you have fiddled with ASP.NET then maybe try reinstalling it.